# Trying get excel table with using padnas from django project

Tags: python, django, pandas

I try get data from table in my Django project from local server

But have a problem after run programm with pandas code:

```
c:\Users\kadzutokun\Desktop\tables.py:3: FutureWarning: Passing literal html to 'read_html' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To read from a literal string, wrap it in a 'StringIO' object.
  tables = pd.read_html(
C:\Users\kadzutokun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py:666: MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning: The input looks more like a filename than markup. You may want to open this file and pass the filehandle into Beautiful Soup.
  soup = BeautifulSoup(udoc, features="html5lib", from_encoding=from_encoding)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    tables = pd.read_html(
  File "C:\Users\kadzutokun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1245, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Users\kadzutokun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1008, in _parse
    raise retained
  File "C:\Users\kadzutokun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 988, in _parse
    tables = p.parse_tables()
  File "C:\Users\kadzutokun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 248, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "C:\Users\kadzutokun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 603, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found
PS C:\Users\kadzutokun> & C:/Users/kadzutokun/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/python.exe c:/Users/kadzutokun/Desktop/tables.py
c:\Users\kadzutokun\Desktop\tables.py:3: FutureWarning: Passing literal html to 'read_html' is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To read from a literal string, wrap it in a 'StringIO' object.
  tables = pd.read_html(
C:\Users\kadzutokun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py:666: MarkupResemblesLocatorWarning: The input looks more like a filename than markup. You may want to open this file and pass the filehandle into Beautiful Soup.
  soup = BeautifulSoup(udoc, features="html5lib", from_encoding=from_encoding)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kadzutokun\Desktop\tables.py", line 3, in <module>
    tables = pd.read_html(
  File "C:\Users\kadzutokun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1245, in read_html
    return _parse(
  File "C:\Users\kadzutokun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 1008, in _parse
    raise retained

  File "C:\Users\kadzutokun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 248, in parse_tables
    tables = self._parse_tables(self._build_doc(), self.match, self.attrs)
  File "C:\Users\kadzutokun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\html.py", line 603, in _parse_tables
    raise ValueError("No tables found")
ValueError: No tables found

pandas code

import pandas as pd

tables = pd.read_html(
    '127.0.0.1:8000/shop/',)

print(len(tables))
```

127.0.0.1:8000/shop/

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O6AE.png)

Please help resolve

Comment: Can you also try with protocol(`http`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@AbdulNiyasPM's intuition is right, try with a protocol. If you pass a string without any protocol, Pandas assumes that you want to parse the string as HTML:

```
tables = pd.read_html('http://127.0.0.1:8000/shop/')
```

Documentation of [pd.read_html](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html):

> **io** (str, path object, or file-like object)
>
> String, path object (implementing os.PathLike[str]), or file-like object implementing a string read() function. **The string can represent a URL or the HTML itself**. Note that lxml only accepts the http, ftp and file url protocols. If you have a URL that starts with 'https' you might try removing the 's'.